# Android call intent with '#' sign as number, prevent Uri.parse remove #

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

I want to call a number with '*140*123456#' or '*141*#123456#'. but the `Uri.parse(phoneNumber)` method removes all '#' signs and numbers after it. What is it's solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
Uri.encode(phoneNumber)
```

to encode unresevered characters

Take a look at [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I change it to `String s = Uri.encode("*141*"+editText.getText().toString()+"#");
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+s));` but it did not work.

Comment: I have to encode only the '#' sign, it worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html).

For **#** it should be `\u0023`

Comment: Thanks for answer, but still have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by replacing the `#` with `%%23` in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
operator = 123
String UssdCodeNew =  "*" + operator + Uri.encode("\u0023");
```